# Select column based on indicator in another column

Tags: r, mutate

I have a dataframe in R where I have a column with a numeric indicator, and I want to create a new column picking from other columns in the dataframe based on that indicator. Probably easiest if I explain via an example...

```
data <- data.frame(
    id = 1:6,
    selction = c(1,4,2,3,2,8),
    column1 = 1:6,
    column2 = 11:16,
    column3 = 21:26,
    column4 = 31:36,
    column5 = 41:46,
    column6 = 51:56,
    column7 = 61:66,
    column8 = 71:76
)
> data
  id selction column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8
1  1        1       1      11      21      31      41      51      61      71
2  2        4       2      12      22      32      42      52      62      72
3  3        2       3      13      23      33      43      53      63      73
4  4        3       4      14      24      34      44      54      64      74
5  5        2       5      15      25      35      45      55      65      75
6  6        8       6      16      26      36      46      56      66      76
```

I would like to create a new column chosing from the columnx columns based on the number in the indicator, i.e. end up with

```
> data
  id selction column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 newcolumn
1  1        1       1      11      21      31      41      51      61      71         1
2  2        4       2      12      22      32      42      52      62      72        32
3  3        2       3      13      23      33      43      53      63      73        13
4  4        3       4      14      24      34      44      54      64      74        24
5  5        2       5      15      25      35      45      55      65      75        15
6  6        8       6      16      26      36      46      56      66      76        76
```

I am trying to avoid doing it with a long ifelse as in reality I could have a lot more than 8 columns. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"["` function will accept a multi-column numeric matrix or array with the same number of columns as there are dimensions in the data object. For dataframes this is always a two column matrix. Subset with row and column index:

```
data[, -c(1:2) ][ cbind(seq(nrow(data)), data$selction) ]
# [1]  1 32 13 24 15 76
```

Here *cbind* gives me rows, 1 to *nrows*, and *data$selection* as the column index, but before subsetting, I am excluding *id* and *selection* columns - `-c(1:2)`.

Could also have added 2 to make a proper offset without the exclusion (Thanks @IRTFM).

```
data[ cbind(seq(nrow(data)), data$selction + 2) ]
# [1]  1 32 13 24 15 76
```

Answer (score 0):

With `diag`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(newcolumn = diag(as.matrix(cur_data()[-c(1, 2)][selection])))

 id selection column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 newcolumn
1  1         1       1      11      21      31      41      51      61      71         1
2  2         4       2      12      22      32      42      52      62      72        32
3  3         2       3      13      23      33      43      53      63      73        13
4  4         3       4      14      24      34      44      54      64      74        24
5  5         2       5      15      25      35      45      55      65      75        15
6  6         8       6      16      26      36      46      56      66      76        76
```

Or with `map`:

```r
library(purrr)
data %>% 
  mutate(newcolumn = map(seq_along(selection), 
                         ~ select(cur_data(), starts_with("column"))[[selection[.x]]][.x]))
```

Comment: The first one is rather diabolical. It took several minutes for me to figure out what was happening. I'd give an upvote if it had an adequate explanation. The second one seemed more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that gets the data and the column which has the selection. Remember to add the +2 to skip the first two columns *Id and Selction* or make a sub selection first. Then run de fucntion and append result as a new result.

```
data <- data.frame(
    id = 1:6,
    selction = c(1,4,2,3,2,8),
    column1 = 1:6,
    column2 = 11:16,
    column3 = 21:26,
    column4 = 31:36,
    column5 = 41:46,
    column6 = 51:56,
    column7 = 61:66,
    column8 = 71:76
)
data
  id selction column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8
1  1        1       1      11      21      31      41      51      61      71
2  2        4       2      12      22      32      42      52      62      72
3  3        2       3      13      23      33      43      53      63      73
4  4        3       4      14      24      34      44      54      64      74
5  5        2       5      15      25      35      45      55      65      75
6  6        8       6      16      26      36      46      56      66      76

selColVal <- function(data,colData){
new_col <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
new_col<- append(new_col,data[i,data[i,"selction"]+2])
   }
return(new_col)
}

a=selColVal(data,data["selction"])
data$new_column <- a

data
       id selction column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 new_column
    1  1        1       1      11      21      31      41      51      61      71       1
    2  2        4       2      12      22      32      42      52      62      72       32
    3  3        2       3      13      23      33      43      53      63      73       13
    4  4        3       4      14      24      34      44      54      64      74       24
    5  5        2       5      15      25      35      45      55      65      75       15
    6  6        8       6      16      26      36      46      56      66      76       76
```